# attempt to index local 'level' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, coronasdk, local

I'm having a runtime error after running the application? it also says that "Handling the unhandled error"

```
LevelDrawer = {
  content = {}
}

function LevelDrawer:reset()
    self.content = {}
end

function LevelDrawer:build(level)
    local level
    for i, item in pairs(level.items) do
        self.content[#self.content + 1] = Item:new(item)
    end
end

return LevelDrawer
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is your question. Do you ask how to fix it? If so, just remove `local level` in `build` function .

Comment: I already remove it and has the same error.. "runtime error "..attempt to index local 'level' (a boolean value) its a boolean not nil typo

Comment: Check what do you pass to `build` function as `level` variable. Does `level.items` exist and does `level.items` is a table object?

Comment: Please show us the part of code where you are calling `LevelDrawer:build` function

Answer (score 3):

You're overwriting the level argument with the line

```
local level
```

Simply remove it to fix your error.

Comment: I already remove it and has the same error.. "runtime error "..attempt to index local 'level' (a boolean value)  its boolean and not nil typo

Comment: If you use `level.items`, `level` in `LevelDrawer:build(level)` must be a table , not a boolean value.